# Running CRM Dynamics 365 as different user shows a blank screen

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

Sometimes, I'm running my Dynamics 365 as a different user on IE browser.
Unlike 2011, in 365, when I'm doing so, at the second\third time I'm running the browser as different user, I'm getting a blank screen with a bold blue line at the top. 
Running it with my(local-admin)user works perfectly.

I think this is something with the IE browser\permissions but I can't tell exactly what and why.
After that blank screen occurs for the first time, even logging in to the pc as the other\different user will end up showing the same blank page from that moment on.

EDIT:
An additional info might help is that every 15 minutes, I can log on successfully , but just for the first time(again). Then, when closing the browser and re-opening it as a different user, the problem occurs again.

[image: CRM Blank Screen]

Comment: Check the url if that says orgname/m/... which means mobile UI.. I faced this sometime.. remove /m/ and change the url to main.aspx it will work..

Comment: unfortunately there is no `m`. so that's not the case

Comment: can you share screenshot?

Comment: @ArunVinoth just updated my post with a screenshot

Comment: did you try fiddler or F12 to diagnose the network & DOM stuffs?